# Is this inequality always valid? $\left|\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}x_i\right|\leq \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}|x_i|$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality, absolute-value

Let $x_i\in\mathbb{R}$ for all $i\in\mathbb{N}.$ Is the following inequality always true?

$$\left|\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}x_i\right|\leq \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}|x_i|$$

Comment: As long as $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}|x_i|$ makes sense (series converges absolutely).

Comment: @r9m: And even if $\sum_{i=0}^\infty|x_i|$ diverges, it can only diverge to $+\infty$, so the inequality is still trivially true in that case.

Comment: @Bungo: I don't think we can say the inequality is trivially true if the left-hand sum does not exist.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Yep, I mentioned that possibility in the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's true as long as $\sum_{i=0}^\infty x_i$ converges. Otherwise the left hand side may be undefined.

To see this, assume that $\sum_{i=0}^\infty x_i$ converges. By the triangle inequality, for every nonnegative integer $N$ we have
$$\left|\sum_{i=0}^{N} x_i\right| \leq \sum_{i=0}^N |x_i| \leq \sum_{i=0}^\infty|x_i|$$
where the rightmost sum may be $+\infty$ (making the inequality trivially true) if the series does not converge absolutely.

Therefore, taking the limit as $N \to \infty$, we have
$$\lim_{N \to \infty} \left|\sum_{i=0}^{N} x_i\right| \leq \sum_{i=0}^\infty|x_i|$$
Since $\sum_{i=0}^\infty x_i$ converges and the absolute value is continuous, it is also true that
$$\lim_{N \to \infty} \left|\sum_{i=0}^{N} x_i\right| = \left|\sum_{i=0}^\infty x_i\right|$$
so the desired result follows.

---

**Edit** to discuss the case where $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} x_i$ diverges in more detail.

Note the distinction: $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} |x_i|$ has nonnegative terms, so if it diverges, it can only diverge to $+\infty$. But $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} x_i$ may diverge by failing to approach any one value (finite or infinite), e.g. $x_i = (-1)^i$. The left hand side doesn't make sense if that happens. The best we can say that if $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} x_i$ converges or if it diverges to $+\infty$ or $-\infty$, then the inequality is true.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is true, if you interpret $+\infty \le +\infty$ and $x \le +\infty$ for all real $x$.

The [triangle inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality) for finitely many terms shows inequality for the partial sums of the series. Taking the limit of both sides gives the desired inequality.

One or both series may diverge to $+\infty$, so the interpretation in my first paragraph is necessary.